# A book (writing, written) in haste may well have a lot of mistake

Tags: past-participles

A book (writing, written) in haste may well have a lot of mistake.

What is the answer? (I don't know which one is correct now.)
Most of us (non-native speaker) say 'written' is correct(the book (which is) written in haste ~) but someone says the answer is 'writing'. (Actually he presented this question.)

Is 'writing' the answer? or is he only misthinked the answer?

Comment: Note that 'book writing' is possible but then it'd serve as a noun - *'a book writing is not an easy task!"*

Comment: @MaulikV - Although then I would phrase it as "*The* writing of *a* book is not an easy task", or maybe use "book" as a noun adjunct with a zero article, as"*Book writing* is not an easy task".

Answer (score 3):

Nope, written is the only correct answer.

If the answer was writing, it would mean that the book was doing the action of the writing and a book cannot write because it has no hands.

***Note:*** Mistake should be plural in this. So,

> A book written in haste may well have a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

A book written in haste may well have a lot of mistakes. The use of written in the sentence is correct grammatically. I think you can also say "A book writing in haste may well cause .......". However, the following are also possible:

1. Writing a book in haste may well cause a lot of mistakes.
2. To write a book in haste may well cause a lot of mistakes.